# What is the date time format given by jstl fmt tag?

Tags: javascript, java, datatables, jstl

To format date and time in JSTL we can use the `fmt` tag as shown [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm)

I have to specify the format of the date for usage in other front end tools like the datatable.
I avoided using any specific formatting with fmt and just used parameters like `type` or `dateStyle` to get a somewhat formatted output. But the **problem** is that **datatables** need to know the **format of date** columns to properly sort these fields.

When I use parameters like

```
<fmt:formatDate type = "both" dateStyle = "long" timeStyle = "long" value = "${now}" />
```

The output is:

> August 23, 2017 10:52:09 AM UTC

How do I specify the format of this date output as:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MMMM dd, YYYY hh:mm:ss aa z' );
```

to get accurate sorting results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
      $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss A', false );
```

Notice that it use the [forgiving mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/forgiving-mode/), because there is no format option to represent the `UTC` part of the date.

Here is the full test case:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>August 23, 2017 10:52:09 AM UTC</td></tr>
            <tr><td>August 23, 2018 10:52:09 AM UTC</td></tr>
            <tr><td>August 21, 2017 10:52:09 AM UTC</td></tr>
            <tr><td>August 23, 2017 08:47:09 PM UTC</td></tr>
            <tr><td>March 29, 2017 10:52:09 AM UTC</td></tr>
            <tr><td>April 01, 2017 10:52:09 AM UTC</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss A', false );
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```